# Prove $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^n\!x}{x^{n+1}}\sin(nx)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^n\!x}{x^n}\cos(nx) \,dx=0$ with induction

Tags: calculus, induction, improper-integrals

There are an elementary integral couple in complex analysis, namely
$$
I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^n\!x}{x^{n+1}}\sin(\alpha x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}, \quad J(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^n\!x}{x^n}\cos(\alpha x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
$$
when $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha\ge n\ge 2$, this couple will always be constants, since they are a basic example for how the analytic function behave while integrated.

Today, I was accidentally asked If this couple degenerate into single integer parameter, denoted as
$$
I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^n\!x}{x^{n+1}}\sin(nx) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}, \quad J_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^n\!x}{x^n}\cos(nx) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0
$$
we already knew this result holds for $n\ge1$ in $I_n$, and for $n\ge2$ in $J_n$, from complex method. **Can it be proved by induction with only real-analytic tool?**

I think it is not hard to do, and soon come up with a possible path, that we can easily check $I_1=\pi/2$ and $J_2=0$, then have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n
& = -\frac1{n}\frac{\sin^n\!x}{x^n}\sin(nx)\biggr|_{x=0}^{\infty} + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)\sin^n\!x+\sin(nx)\sin^{n-1}\!x\cos x}{x^n} \,\mathrm{d}x\\
& = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n+1)x\sin^{n-1}\!x}{x^n} \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{aligned}
$$
hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_n=\frac1{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\sin(n+1)x-\sin(n-1)x)\sin^{n-1}\!x}{x^n} \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{I_n-I_{n-1}}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
or literally
$$
I_n-I_{n-1}=2J_n
$$
Then if only we can find other formula for $J_n$ or to prove $J_n=0$, the proof is surely complete. But that is what I can't finish in a quick glimpse, so I put here for further suggestion, and always, thanks in advance.